# Java Inheritance with already created superclass

Tags: java, inheritance

Lets say i have a Super class `Person` and subclass `Employee`
I would like to create a `person` class first and then use it as a param to be placed into my `employee` class's constructor.

E.g. `Public Empolyee`(Person person....) (This produces a constructor not found error during compile time)

My Case scenario is that i have a `Person` object that has not been instantiated as an employee yet and later on i would like to use it to instantiate an `Employee` object and I would like to pass this person's variables over.

So how do i do this? Also please do explain if it should be done this way or not.

Comment: still confused what you are trying to ask.

Comment: This depends on what you are trying to achieve.  Generally what you say is possible but the details depends on what you are trying to achieve.  Espcially if we get to the part "explain if it should be done this way or not".

Comment: I don't understand where the problem is. If you want to add a param to your constructor, just add a param to your constructor.

Comment: I was looking at an example same as the answer shown below where the llya suggested i change the relationship. So i was testing out if it was possible in the inheritance scenario. As i am pretty new to this i wanted to find out why it might be redundant to do so

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Child` class automatically gets access of all the `public, protected` members of the `parent` and `child` also has reference to `parent` class.

why you want to pass `parent` class reference to `Child` class. Instead you can call `parent` class constructor from `child` class like this:

```
public Child(){
super()
}
```

According to the question below, we can do this:

```
public class Child1 extends Super1 {
    private int l;
    public Child1(Super1 s){
        super(s);
    }
    public Child1(){
        this.l=20;
    }
}

public class Super1 {
    private int k;
    public Super1(){

    }
    public Super1(Super1 s){
        k=s.k;
    }
}
```

Comment: Lets say i already have an existing person object but it has not been instantiated as an employee, now later on if i choose to created a employee instance with that person object? *Bear with me I am just trying to learn more about the concept of inheritance*

Comment: @SatrughanKumarSingh just see my edit. does it answer your question?

Comment: Yes it worked, thank you for being patient. I started programming because of the wonderful support I see from the community. New guys like us will tend to ask silly questions at times but it is in the name of learning as much as we can

Comment: @SatrughanKumarSingh always welcome if you liked the answer you can up vote as well thanks. :-).

Comment: I am pretty new here, will definitely come back and upvote once i get 15 rep score

Answer (score 2):

You directly get access to all Person class members via Employee class due to the inheritance relationship. You dont need to pass parent object to a child.

Pass all the necessary parameters to Employee and call super() from its constructor.

```
//Person constructor
Person(param1, param2){
}

class Employee extends Person
//Employee constructor
Employee(param1, param2){
super(param1, param2);
}

// New object
Employee emp = new Employee(param1, param2);
```

Also constructor dont return anything so remove the void in your question.

Comment: Ok, but lets say i have already created a person object and i would like the employee class to grab variables from this person object 
e.g. 
Person psn = new Person(...);
Employee emp = new Employee(psn, ..., ...);

Can it be done in such a way that this is possible?

Comment: You can use a copy constructor for the Person class and call that in the Employee class constructor for your specific case.

Answer (score 0):

i dont see your inheritance logic here correctly.

you have answer already..see below

```
class person()


class employee extends person(here)
```

hence you get to access its variables and methods..

just curious why you need to instantiate employee and injecting person class which is already parent to employee.

Comment: I was looking at an example same as the answer shown just above this answer where the llya suggested i change the relationship. So i was testing out if it was possible in the inheritance scenario. As i am pretty new to this i wanted to find out why it might be redundant to do so

Comment: in terms of java, it is not inheritance, bcoz java will understand only if you follow the notions, as said in the answer, For e.g in your testing code you cant assign child class to parent reference. Person(type) employee1 = Employee() ..since you are not defining the relationship between employee and person with 'extends' keyword. the answer i have given you can do that..

Answer (score 0):

Your Employee will work as a person.You can call every method or variable (except private variables and methods) of Person by Employee object. But still if you want to pass a Person object to the constructor of Employee class then you can do it as fallows-

```
  public Employee(Person person,.......){
      super();//or pass required parameters according to constructor of Person class
         //do whatever you want
   }
```

it will work perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
//if your Person constructor looks like this
public Person(param1, param2){
}


//then your copy constructor would look like this
public Employee(Person p){
   super(p.getParam1 p.getParam2);
}
```